# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Tags: java, android

> E/Volley: [7259] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code
>   400 for https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

When I press a button, it's sending above error message.
I tested it on my phone.

I think the problem is in code below,
but I couldn't find it.

Please help me to solve this problem.

```
public void sendData(JSONObject requestData, final SendResponseListener listener) {
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", requestData,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    listener.onRequestCompleted();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            listener.onRequestWithError(error);
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "key=(API key)");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }
    };

    request.setShouldCache(false);
    listener.onRequestStarted();
    queue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: minor text adjustments